# Not working Jobscheduler on android 8.1.0 & android 7.1.2

Tags: android, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler

Jobscheduler is not working on android 8.1.0 emulator and redmi phone 7.1.2.

**Problem:

1)(a) Job run only once, if app is not close.

  (b) without connecting to internet start jobscheduler and kill app force fully by clearing the background task. After that enabled internet, Job is not running even once.

2) Job is not getting schedule again as enabled in onStart with jobFinished parameter enabled.

3) stop button is not showing list of pending task after job is executed once, as already enabled to run again on onStart**

Can Someone help me, where is the mistake in code in following code

JobService class :

```
public class MyService extends JobService {
      @Override
      public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            jobFinished(params,true);
            return false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            jobFinished(params,true);
            return true;
      }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<service android:name=".MyService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    Button start,stop;
    JobScheduler jobScheduler;
    JobInfo jobInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        start=findViewById(R.id.start);
        stop=findViewById(R.id.stop);
        jobScheduler= (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        start.setOnClickListener(this);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       if(v==start){
         ComponentName componentName=new ComponentName(this,MyService.class);
        JobInfo.Builder builder=new JobInfo.Builder(9898,componentName);
        builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);
        builder.setPersisted(true);
        //builder.setOverrideDeadline(10000);
        builder.setOverrideDeadline(10000);
        //builder.setBackoffCriteria(5000,JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR);
        jobInfo=builder.build();
        jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
    }

    if(v==stop){
        for(JobInfo j: jobScheduler.getAllPendingJobs()){
            //if(j.getId()==9){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Pending "+j.getId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

}